# Need the correct number criteria for a search query

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've been working for a few days on a small project that searches a table for criteria entered in four TextBoxes, using a ListBox linked to a query that finds the results. My problem is that I can search the text datatype fields just fine, but there is a field called 'Age', and I cannot find the correct criteria syntax to put in the query.

The criteria I used is this: `Like "*" & [forms]![SearchTab]![schAge] & "*"`

It works fine for text fields, but not for the one number field.
There isn't much VBA code, just for the OnChange of the TextBox to Requery the list box like this:

```
Private Sub schAge_Change()
    Dim SAge as Variant
    SAge = schAge.Value
    Me.lstResults.Requery
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to filter/search for records where some strings can be found? Then use.

```
Like '*" & [forms]![SearchTab]![schAge] & "*'"
```

Otherwise,

```
= " & [forms]![SearchTab]![schAge] & "
```

Also, since you are using `Change`event, use `schAge.Text`to get the last text input.  `schAge.Value` will only return the last value beforeUpdate of the textbox. *Note: I didn't see any relation of this code from above. Where are you using SAge?*

```
Private Sub schAge_Change() 
  Dim SAge as Variant 
  SAge = schAge.Text
  Me.lstResults.Requery 
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks. SAge is supposed to be the variable that passes the value of the text box to the query.

Comment: is there a better criteria that I can use instead of '*" . maybe one that can search for text according to the first letter typed to match the first letter in the field and not anywhere within the field.

Comment: if you want first letter then do like `Like 't*'` so the results will be like all text starting from t.